# Difficulties importing data into Seaborn Boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, csv, seaborn

*EDIT: A solution was provided by user #kgoettler below. The problem arise from Seaborn Boxplot requiring data to be organized by variable in the x-axis and values in the y-axis. The script below reorganizes the data into a form compatible with Seaborn Boxplot.*

ORIGINAL QUESTION: My goal is to generate a Box plot using data from an CSV file. I would like to use the Python visualization library Seaborn. The data is organized with a common index (Object) and headers for each column.

[image: Image of raw data]

I have difficulties importing this data into a Boxplot using the format

```
seaborn.boxplot(x="variable", y="value")
```

Using Pandas own boxplot this is not a problem since I simply specify what columns to use based on headers using the following format

```
boxplot = data.boxplot(column=['header1', 'header2', 'header3'])
```

[image: Image of panda boxplot using raw data]

I would also prefer not to have to specify each individual column by header, but rater select all columns in the file automatically.

All feedback and input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

csv_file = '/path/to/file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df = (df
        .set_index(['Object'])          # Set 'Object' column to index
        .rename_axis("Metric", axis=1)  # Rename the column axis "Metric"
        .stack()                        # Stack the columns into the index
        .rename('Score')                # Rename the remaining column 'Score'
        .reset_index()                  # Reset the index
    )
```

This should give you a DataFrame that looks like:

```py
   Object                       Metric     Score
0     MT1  B1A1 Average Splaying Score  0.426824
1     MT1  B1A2 Average Splaying Score  0.431351
2     MT1  B1A3 Average Splaying Score  1.941473
3     MT2  B1A1 Average Splaying Score -0.021672
4     MT2  B1A2 Average Splaying Score  3.357387
```

Then to plot, all you have to do is:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='Metric', y='Score', data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIaNY.png)

Comment: Thank you! (Especially for the nice in-script comments). I removed "csv_file = '/path/to/file.csv'" since I am using jupyter notebook which sets the path automatically and it worked. After some consideration I think I understand what you are doing here and I'll modify my original post so people have an easier time looking for solutions to the same problem.

Comment: Railsware had good explanation of how Axis work in Pandas which may be of use to anyone finding this in the future and want to understand the solution script.

https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-pandas-axis-explained/